# Argument recycling does not appear to work

Tags: r

The following is a recreation of A data frame and A function that produce the following error:

```
Error in Ops.data.frame(sF1(x1, x2, x3, x4), sF1(x1, x2, 0, x4)) (from #2) : 
          - only defined for equally-sized data frames"
```

The data frame

```
S <- rep(c(1,2), each=1536)
D <- rep(c(0,2,4,6,8,10,15,20,30,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,80,85,90,92,94,96,98,100), each=16,times=16)
K <- rep(c("K", "Y","M","C"), each= 384, times=4)
I <- rep(c("A", "S"), each=3072)
Data <- rnorm(6144)
DataFrame <- cbind.data.frame(S,D,K,I,Data)
```

I created two functions each with the same four arguments

```
sF1 <-  function(x1,x2,x3,x4) subset(DataFrame, I == x1 & K == x2 & D == x3 & S==x4, select = "Data")

sF2 <- function(x1,x2,x3,x4){
    (100* (1-10^-(sF1(x1,x2,x3,x4) - sF1(x1,x2,0,x4))) /
     (1-10^-(sF1(x1,x2,100,x4)- sF1(x1,x2,0,x4)))) - x3}
```

The function 'sF1' runs with no problem

```
sF1(I,K,D,S)
```

In the second function 'sF2' produces the above error

```
sF2(I,K,D,S)
```

The following is a breakdown of 'sF2' components:

- sF1(x1,x2,x3,x4) has 5632 rows
- sF1(x1,x2,0,x4) has 256 rows, which I expect that it would recycle 22 times
- sF1(x1,x2,100,x4) also has 256 rows, which I expect that it would recycle 22 times

I am guessing the error is due to the lack of recycling. Do I need to format my data frame differently? Do I need to rewrite the function 'sF2'? I have been spinning my weel all day with no success. Please help correct this error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subset` is not recommended for programatic use. use `[` instead.

That being said, given that you want to return single column from the data.frame, if you don't keep the `data.frame` class (which subset does, or `[..., ,drop = FALSE]` would, then recylcing works as you would expect.

I'm not clear you really want `==`, not `I%in%(unique(x1)` or similar (but will leave that as an exercise

You could redefine

```
sF1 <-  function(x1,x2,x3,x4) with(DataFrame, Data[I == x1 & K == x2 & D == x3 & S==x4])
```

which would return a vector which would recycle

Comment: Thank you mnel for your help, i modified the sF1 as follows:

Comment: `with` is not recommend for programmatic use either, for the same reasons as `subset`.